# Viviani's theorem using Pythagoras

Tags: geometry

Did anyone find the proof of [Viviani's Theorem](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FViviani%2527s_theorem&ei=iW6VVI3qBMbhuQSwhIHgCQ&usg=AFQjCNFc_nUUH39mP3gSM8hZ6LETSNL7PQ) just by using Pythagoras' relations in the triangles? 
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: To prove that $ML+MK+MH$ is constant through Pythagoras' theorem would be equivalent to prove that the sum of three square roots is constant. This is obviously possible but rather ugly, especially if compared to the beauty of the relation $$AB(ML+MK+MH)=AB\cdot ML+AC\cdot MK+BC\cdot MH = 2\Delta.$$

Comment: I try to prove that : $(ML + MK + MH)^{2} = AJ^{2}$ , I don't understand your last relation.

Comment: the middle term is the sum of twice the areas of $MAB,MBC,MCA$, hence twice the area of $ABC$. It is just the usual proof.

Comment: Oh ok it is the usual method indeed. But it is harder with Pythagoras' relations... Did you succeed ?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Did you find the solution by using Pythagoras relations ? 
Thanks

Comment: no, I haven't succeded, but maybe we can exploit two interesting facts: in a triangle $ABC$, the area of the pedal triangle of a point $P$ depends only on the (squared) distance between $P$ and the circumcenter of $ABC$ (Euler pedal triangle theorem), while the moment of inertia $PA^2+PB^2+PC^2$ depends only on the (squared) distance between $P$ and the centroid $G$ (Huygens-Steiner theorem). Since in an equilateral $ABC$ we have $O\equiv G$, maybe these two theorems prove the Viviani's one.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio good idea but difficult for me.
Here is what I started :
I want to prove that : $(ML + MK + MH)^{2} = AJ^{2}$

In $\triangle ABJ$ : $AB^{2} = BJ^{2} + AJ^{2}$
In $\triangle ACJ$ : $AC^{2} = BJ^{2} + CJ^{2}$
In $\triangle AML$ : $AM^{2} = AL^{2} + ML^{2}$
In $\triangle BML$ : $BM^{2} = BL^{2} + ML^{2}$
In $\triangle BMH$ : $BM^{2} = BH^{2} + MH^{2}$
In $\triangle CMH$ : $CM^{2} = CH^{2} + MH^{2}$
In $\triangle CMK$ : $CM^{2} = CK^{2} + MK^{2}$
In $\triangle AMK$ : $AM^{2} = AK^{2} + MK^{2}$

Then I write $AJ^{2}=AB^{2}-AC^{2}+CJ^{2}=Ab^{2}-AC^{2}+\frac{BC^{2}}{4}$
I stopped here.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I try to project $M$ on $[AJ]$, this new point is $V$. Maybe Pythagoras' relations are easier to apply on a point of $[AJ]$. What do you think of this idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: Honestly I don't know if this will lead you somewhere. How would you deal with the terms $ML\cdot MK,ML\cdot MH,MK\cdot MH$ coming from the square of $ML+MK+MH$? Their sum is obviously related with the area of $HLK$, but this points back to the standard proof.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio So we can conclude that Viviani's theorem cannot be solved by using Pythagoras theorem ? Exciting ^^

Comment: the fact that the both of us haven't found a path does not imply that such a path does not exist.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry again but do you think that the fact of using Stewart's theorem could be helpful here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, here's a picture with some edges given labels:
[image: Picture]
and here's the equations that the Pythagorean Theorem spits out, assuming $AB=BC=CA=1$:
$$a^2+\gamma^2=(1-c)^2+\beta^2$$
$$b^2+\alpha^2=(1-a)^2+\gamma^2$$
$$c^2+\beta^2=(1-b)^2+\alpha^2$$

And guess what! It is impossible to show the desired result that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\frac{\sqrt{3}}2$ using just the equations. It does not, for instance, guarantee that $M$ lies in the same plane as $ABC$, and, if not, the result fails. To be really explicit, the points $L$, $K$, and $H$ can be taken to be the perpendicular projection of $M$ onto each of those lines, which exists for any $M$ and will always satisfy the Pythagorean identities, but if $M$ is not on the plane of $ABC$ (or is outside $ABC$), the sum of the altitudes will be greater than expected. Thus, satisfying the Pythagorean identities does not imply that Viviani's theorem will be satisfied.

For instance, algebraically, if we set $a=b=c=\frac{1}2$, then $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$, this *always* solves the set of three equations, but $\alpha+\beta+\gamma$ could be anything. This could represent choosing the point $M$ to be somewhere far off on the line perpendicular to the plane $ABC$ through the centroid of $ABC$. However, things get worse - we can choose the lengths to be too small, where we lose even more of our geometric intuition. In fact, though our original situation satisfies the equations, so does any situation that looks as follows:

[image] 
where, for instance $M_1$ and $M_2$ are equidistant from $A$. Notice that we still have the appropriate right triangles and are still satisfying every equality we had, but this is most certainly not what we wished to represent, especially when we consider that we don't need to stay on the plane for this either - and these cases are clearly not subject to Viviani's theorem.

The problem is that the Pythagorean theorem only tells us that triangles are right triangles. We need a lot more restrictions than that to describe our situation. In particular, we need some restriction to make sure that $M$ is within the triangle (and a nice algebraic condition for that is the converse of Viviani's theorem). We also need to somehow restrict that $M$ is actually just one point and not three points. You need more relations to describe this situation - and figuring out what those relations should be is far from trivial.

(As an interesting aside, if we sum up all the equations, then expand and cancel terms, we get that $a+b+c=\frac{3}2$, which is curious and has a similar form to what we wanted - but it's not quite Viviani's theorem, since it describes the wrong lengths. It does, however, apply in *any* situation described by those equations, including the strange second one)

Comment: It's strange that we can't solve the problem with Pythagoras.. You only have 3 equations from Pythagoras' relations but you could have more if you consider $AKM$ or the other triangles. It will give 3 more and maybe we can obtain link between these relations.

Comment: @Maman I did use all $6$ triangles; in particular, my equations each represent two applications of the Pythagorean theorem; for instance, on $AKM$, we get $$(1-c)^2+\beta^2 = AM^2$$ and on $ALM$, we get $a^2+\gamma^2=AM^2$. What I did was to equate these to each other and drop the equality with $AM^2$ - no matter how we choose our variables, we can satisfy that $(1-c)^2+\beta^2=a^2+\gamma^2=AM^2$ by  choosing $AM=\sqrt{a^2+\gamma^2}$. So, as a matter of fact, the only useful relations yielded by the $6$ right triangles in the figure are the three that I include.

Comment: Also, notice that all six right triangles in the original figure have corresponding right triangles in the second figure - so the second situation is still satisfying all the possible relations we could get out of the Pythagorean theorem. Really, what we'd need is some algebraic condition that describes the possible distances between $4$ points on a plane - and I don't have such a thing readily at hand, nor would I expect to have a nice form (it would be a quadratic polynomial in six variables - the pairwise distances - and would likely have 22 monomial terms)